# Performing regression with 1-d response and a 2-d predictor?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, data-visualization, matlab

I have a dataset I'm trying to figure out how to properly analyze. I'm exploring both how hours spent studying and timing of preparation correlate with test outcomes.

The model is as such: response = test scores; predictor = hours spent studying per month before the test

e.g.

```
        PREDICTOR         RESPONSE
       hours spent          score

       jan feb mar  ...     
stud1 | 1   3   9   ... |   0.91
stud2 | 1   2   5   ... |   0.85
stud3 | 0   2   4   ... |   0.75
  ... | ... ... ...     |   ...
```

I began to analyze the data by performing linear regressions on each month (as individual predictors) for test scores, but then the question becomes too specific (i.e., "how do total hours spent studying *in March* predict test outcomes" and so on). I then thought to break the timeline into chunks (total hours before January, before April, before September, etc.; total hours overall), but I fear to lose data richness.

What types of regression or other analysis would you recommend be used to describe and visualize (perhaps in 3d) the relationship? My experience is in MATLAB, but I'm open to general suggestions or approaches on other platforms.

Comment: You might consider trying a weighted regression, where the largest weights are for most recent study hours per month and the smallest weights are for oldest study hours per month.